# Resharper and Test categories

Tags: resharper

In TestDriven.Net I can set the following from the TestDriven.Net Options Pane

1. Run tests in all categories
2. Exclude tests in categories
3. Include tests in categories

and they will be set once where I can add a comma seperated list.
See http://weblogs.asp.net/nunitaddin/archive/2008/12/03/testdriven-net-options-pane.aspx

Can this be done in resharper where I only have to do this once and it applies accross all sessions even when I close a session down?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It doesn't look like there's a way to filter by category right now.  However, in the Unit Test Sessions view, the tests can be "Group By: Categories" and then you could select only the categories you wanted to run.  Doesn't look like there's a way to do this across all sessions though.

This seems like a good feature to have - a few days ago the [resharper twitter account posted](http://twitter.com/resharper/status/9739243622):

> We have branched! 5 will focus on
>   Optimization and Fixes. vNext will aim
>   for EAP in Summer. Want some feature?
>   Good time to let us know!